# New Text field when Button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, textfield

I have a problem that hopefully someone can help me with. I have a webpage I've been building with html and php that has text fields that you fill out and submit to create an evaluation. What I would like to do is be able to click the Add Another Criteria button to add another criteria name and description field to the page and the Add criteria and create buttons would then go below the newest set of text fields created.
[image: Create Evaluation Page]

All this information is going to be stored in a database using PHP controller files so I am not sure if using Javascript would be the best way to achieve my goal. I apologize for my lack of php knowledge I am very new to this any help would be much appreciated Thank you!

Comment: You want to add all 4 fields again and again user clicks on `Add Another Criteria` right?

Comment: no just the fields labeled Criteria Name and Description. the top two would not need to be repeated.

Comment: And how you planned to save all fields in db?

Comment: using php controllers to store the information to the database.

Comment: can you share your existing html and JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier if you're using jQuery, but without, it's still possible.

```js
    var newCriteria = document.createElement("input");
    newCriteria.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Criteria Name');
    newCriteria.name = 'criteria[]';

    var newDesc = document.createElement("textarea");
    newDesc.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Description');
    newDesc.name = 'description[]';

    document.getElementById("theForm").appendChild(newCriteria);
    document.getElementById("theForm").appendChild(newDesc);
```

On the PHP side, using the brackets will make the value come through as an array:

```
 for ($x = 0; $x < $_POST['criteria']; $x++) {
    // do something with each $_POST['criteria'][$x] and $_POST['description'][$x]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'll give this a shot it seems like my best option I'll let you know if it works out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to add an onClick Listener and add the fields:

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  $("#containertoappend").append('<input type="text" id="anothercriteria" placeholder="Another criteria">');
  $("#containertoappend").append('<textarea id="anotherdescription" placeholder="Another Description"></textarea>');
});
```